# Need a way to define input arguments for constructor in interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, constructor

First of all, I know it isn't possible to define constructors in interfaces in Java. But somehow, I've run into a problem where I need something very similar. Maybe there is an easy solution for my case...

I have an interface:

```
public interface SomeObject {

    /**
     * Generate a xml representation of the object.
     */
    public String generateXMLRepresentation();

}
```

This xml-representation of the object will be stored somewhere and later on it should be possible to construct a copy of the object using this xml-representation. My intial thought was to define a constructor which takes a String as input and let every implementation of SomeObject know how to handle it and how to construct the corresponding object.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** Either I wasn't clear enough about that or I think about it the wrong way but I think that Factory or Builder patterns won't work. I need something stronger where everyone can write a new implementation of SomeObject and is forced to implement an constructor which takes an xml string. To put it another way, I do not how many or which implementations of SomeObject exist and still, I'm relying on that every implementation knows how to construct itself from an xml-representation.

Comment: How can you achieve what?

Comment: Factory design pattern?

Comment: It seems restrictive to try to impose a String constructor by whatever means (Factory and Builder patterns are possible ways of encouraging implementors to do this). It seems all you are concerned about is that an XML representation can be generated as a String. So what do you care about how the implementations of the interface are constructed?

Comment: The implementations may of course have other constructors. I just want to make sure that they always **can** be constructed from an xml-representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for this you should use the **[Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)**, since we are talking about building up an object based on a string.

So you should have different static methods constructing different implementations for a given String.

```
public class ObjV1 implements SomeObject(){ // objects would simply extend interface
    ...
}

public class SomeObjectFactory{// factory would provide construction methods for different implementations of the interface

   //Hide factory constructor, so we use it only as a singleton
   private SomeObjectFactory(){
   }

   public static ObjV1 buildV1(String str){
      ObjV1 obj = new ObjV1(); // note that we're using the noarg constructor
      ...
      return obj;
   }
}
```

If you want to have more control over the building process, you should give the **[Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)** a try

Answer (score 0):

Some Design Patterns can help you to define a solution that can handle your current context. Both the [Abstract Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) and the [Builder](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) pattern can help you.

I'd rather go with the Builder design pattern. You'll end up being able to construct from simple to complex objects based solely on that XML representation you have by implementing the proper logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider separating the concern of xml serialisation from whatever concern your object is dealing with.  Is knowledge of to and from xml really intrinsic to the domain of your class, or is it an orthogonal concern?

Have a look at http://x-stream.github.io/

If you do not want to use xstream itself, because you can't depend on the jar, or your xml form is particular to your project, at least look at what xstream does.  You should be able to define a single strategy to (reflectively?) recurse an object structure and write out xml in the form you require, and a companion class to do the opposite.